# How to associate an antivirus with a file to delete it wherever it detects the file?

Tags: virus-removal

How to associate an antivirus with a file to delete it wherever it detects the file?

I want My ESET Smart security 8 to delete a specific file wherever the file is .

or not allow the file to run.

what should I do?

Comment: This is a very application-specific configuration. Please contact the vendor.

Comment: I actually wrote a program do to this, it works against specific filenames, and does not take file location into account. Renaming the file would allow it to run